# mkdir error: no such file or directory

Tags: mkdir

on a linux machine running CENTOS v 7.8.2003 I am in a directory `Neutrinos`
I now do 
`mkdir /pionloop/`
this works. I then go to into this new directory `pionloop` and do
`mkdir /E_0.3`
and this works as well. I thus have as a result a directory `Neutrinos/pionloop/E_0.3`.

Now, starting in `Neutrinos` I want to do this in one command and therefore do
`mkdir /pionloop/E_0.3`
and get:
`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/pionloop/E_3.0’: No such file or directory

What is going wrong here??

Comment: Please copy/paste the commands as you use them. If you run `mkdir /pionloop/` you'll get `/pionloop`, not `./pionloop`.

Comment: Also, `mkdir /E_0.3` would not create a subdirectory of `/pionloop`. And neither of them would be located in `Neutrinos`.

Comment: You can take the first two comments as a request for clarifications. Do consider updating your question with what it is you want to do. I can imagine that you'd like to create `Neutrinos/pionloop/E_0.3` in the current directory, but this is never actually stated, and you confuse matters by showing commands for creating directories in the root directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `mkdir`, does not create missing intermediate directories.

As mentioned in the manual (`man mkdir`), you can create them with the `-p` flag

```
mkdir -p pionloop/E_0.3
```